# How can I run a second query against results from my first query?

Tags: mysql

Here is the updated scenario, hope this is clearer than the last version.

Table 1 is where all data for this process is housed and contains around 5 million records.

```
`table1`
ID   Forename Surname Tel  Source Optin DistributedDate
1    A        Test    0131 TL037  NULL  NULL
2    B        Test    0141 TL035  NULL  NULL
v    v        v       v    v      v     v
```

Table 2 is updated via an insert script and contains a distinct list of sources used within a period of time, this could just as easily be created by a view.

```
INSERT INTO table2(`Sourcecode`)
(SELECT DISTINCT(a.`Sourcecode`) FROM `table1` a)

`table2 - structure`
ID  Sourcecode
1   TL037
2   TL031
3   TL004
4   TL029
5   TL035
```

I am now trying to pull back the details of 5 random records from each distinct source from table 2 and insert these details into table 3.

```
`table3 - structure`
ID   Forename Surname Tel  Source Optin DistributedDate
NULL NULL     NULL    NULL NULL   NULL  NULL
```

This is the code I've created so far:

```
SET @Sourcecode = 
(SELECT b.`Sourcecode`
FROM `table2` b
WHERE b.id = b.id
AND b.`Sourcecode` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(source) FROM `table3`)
LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO table3.*
(SELECT 
a.id AS 'ID',
a.`FirstName` AS 'Forename',
a.`Surname` AS 'Surname',
a.`TelephoneNumber2` AS 'Tel',
a.`SourceCode` AS 'Source',
a.`optin` AS 'Optin',
a.`DateExported` AS 'DistributedDate'
FROM `table1` 
WHERE  a.`SourceCode` = @SourceCode
ORDER BY RAND(a.sourcecode)
LIMIT 5
```

Basically the end result I'm looking for is to run the above queries multiple times automatically from the result-set against @Sourcecode until value is NULL.

I've tried this using the loop function but I'm not having much luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View like this:

```
CREATE VIEW query1 AS
SELECT DISTINCT(b.`source`)
FROM `table2` b
```

Then collect from the View as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1` a
WHERE a.`source` IN(DISTINCT(b.`source`) FROM `query1` b)
ORDER BY RAND(a.id)
LIMIT 5)
```

I haven't tested it myself, if this doesn't work, please give some source and expected data.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response,  don't think this will pull the results i am after unfortunately. Say the first selection was to pull back 5 different sources, I would then require 5 ids from each of the sources to populate, so 25 records in total. The issue is i never know how many sources are going to be pulled back and even if i did and set the `rand` function to 25, it would never get me 5 from each source. Sorry if this doesn't make scene, its my first post on this site.

Comment: If possible update your original question with some sample data, whatdoes your table look like, and what do you want as output? (if Galma's answer isn't sufficient that is).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, A2.RAND_NUMBER
FROM `table1` a, (SELECT DISTINCT(b.`source`)
                 ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @INT AS RAND_NUMBER
                  FROM `table2` b) AS A2
WHERE A2.RAND_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 5
GROUP BY a.id, A2.RAND_NUMBER
ORDER BY RAND(a.id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the TOP function isn't reconsidered in the version of mySQL I am using.

Comment: Not sure what you are meaning with the `NewId()` part?